# まあいいじゃん meaning

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> それじゃ遅い。遅すぎるよ、小夜子ねーちゃん。
>
> 喩えるなら…そう、後で買えばいいと思っていたものが、いざ欲しい時に売り切れていた…みたいな？
>
> 分かるような分からないような…
>
> あはは、**まあいいじゃん**。

In this case the speaker was trying to tell the listener why they want do this as fast as they can, they tried to liken it using the example and the listener didn't quite get it. They then followed it up with まあいいじゃん, before starting another sentence explaining other reasons why they wanted to do it. Is this まあいいじゃん, just like a way of saying "never mind", or "don't worry about it"? (referring to her example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm by no means anything more than a beginner, but I've both used (and had the skit script I wrote it in scrutinized for grammar and spelling) and heard 「まあいいじゃん」 used to say "it doesn't matter", "whatever then, it's okay if you're not clear on it", which are just slightly different words for "never mind", "don't worry about it", so yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I like to think of まあいいじゃん as a short form of まあいいじゃない, meaning somewhere along the lines of "well that's fine anyways" or "that's okay".