# Meaning of いーじゃん

Tags: meaning, translation, colloquial-language

I am reading 海街 Diary, and I have come across the dialogue below. For context: The older sister of the female protagonist calls her, and then has a go at her because her phone was switched off and she needed to get hold of her urgently.

At this point, the female protagonist, taken aback, says:

> いーじゃん別にそれよりなによ～？

I am guessing the meaning is "Why, what's going on?", but I couldn't find the meaning of いーじゃん anywhere. I think this may be very colloquial.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25869/%e3%81%be%e3%81%82%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%82%93-meaning

Comment: It’s worth pointing out in addition to the answer that grammatically it’s a contraction of いいじゃない(？), meaning “it’s good/fine, isn’t it?” (in a very literal translation).

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to use いいじゃん, and in a lot of cases the phrase is hard to render accurately in English. So it's well nigh impossible, in my opinion, to give an accurate and comprehensive answer to your title question: What's the meaning of いいじゃん.

Just to sample a few usages of いいじゃん:

> 悲しいなら、泣けばいいじゃん
> If you are sad, cry (literally: isn't it good if you cry)

> A: デートに誘われたんだ！
> Someone asked me out!
>
> B: いいじゃん！行ってみなよ
> Nice! Just go have fun.

Here, you should note the 別に which imparts dismissive undertones especially when used in conjunction with いいじゃん. The usage is 別にいいじゃん or いいじゃん別に, and the general idea is unconcern, or impatience, or sometimes even flippancy. "I don't care." but not so explicit. Literally it's like "It's okay, isn't it?" Depending on the context, it can go anywhere between "alright!" "I know!" to "I don't give a damn!" Here I think a simple "Alright!" or "Okay!" would do.

> いーじゃん別にそれよりなによ～？
> Alright! By the way what did you need to find me for?

Answer (score 2):

いーじゃん別に (and I specifically speak to cases with 別に) typically means disagreement to some issue being raised as a big deal, i.e. hey, don't make a big fuss about it. It's an idiom.

> A. でもさーこのお店、おしぼりくれないんだぜ？ Dude, this place doesn't even give you
> oshibori (a hand/face towel that comes out when you sit down at a
> restaurant)

> B. いーじゃん別に Chill, man.

When I translate, I can 100% match "chill , man" to "いーじゃん別に", a rarity in English-Japanese translation.